# Is it possible to encapsulate a template in an Angular component without creating a dom element?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use the cdkDrag directive from angular material inside a custom component, but it doesn't work. I believe that it is because the element with cdkDrag is not the direct child of a cdkDropList element anymore, as angular creates a new element in DOM for my component. I tried to use cdkDragRootElement but it didn't work either. So I was thinking if there is a way that doesn't create a new dom element.

Following the example in angular material (https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists) it works but when I wrap the cdkDrag div in a component it looses it's behavior.

Working example:

```
<div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="todo"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Not working, inside my custom component:

```
<div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="todo"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <app-drag *ngFor="let item of todo" [item]='item'></app-drag>
</div>
```

app-drag template:

```
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
```

It renders as deserved, but when i try to drag and drop elements it looses its connection to the cdkDropList element. I don't get any errors in console either.